i am facing the issue of the AVD is terminated
i am facing the issue of the Avd is terminated in the new version of Android studio (ladbug 2024.2) and the root cause  of is following:  WARN - #com.android.sdklib.deviceprovisioner.DeviceAction - The emulator process for AVD Pixel_7_Pro_API_35 has terminated. com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$EmulatorTerminatedException:
i have tried everthing from wipe data, to SDK updation, etc
please help with these issue as soon as possible
i am expecting to get my android emulator run
